# Remove multiple object from array of objects using filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Given,

```
someArray = [{name:"Kristian", lines:"2,5,10"},
             {name:"John", lines:"1,19,26,96"},
             {name:"Brian",lines:"3,9,62,36" }];

removeArray = [{name:"Kristian", lines:"2,5,10"},
             {name:"Brian",lines:"3,9,62,36" }];
```

How do I remove objects of removeArray from someArray?
I can remove a single object:

```
johnRemoved = someArray.filter(function(el) {
return el.name !== "John";
});
```

However, instead of comparing someArray names to a string, I'd like to compare them to names in removeArray. Can it be done with a second filter method or does it have to be a for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the answers given here. I wanted to add my own as well.

1 - Two [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) methods, first filter used for iteration:

```js
removeArray.filter(function(ra) {
    someArray = someArray.filter(function(sa) {
        return sa.name !== ra.name;
    });
});
```

2 - first iteration can be replaced by [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop

```
for (let item of removeArray){
```

3- or by [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
removeArray.forEach(function(ra) {
```

4- as [dubbha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47105605/3481709), [Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47105610/3481709) and [Jonas w](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47105541/3481709) mentioned, [Array.prototype.some(](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)):

```
someArray.filter(i => !removeArray.some(j => j.name === i.name));
```

5- lastly [trincot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47105528/3481709)'s answer was interesting for me:

```
someArray = someArray.filter(function(obj) {
  return !this.has(obj.name);
}, new Set(removeArray.map(obj => obj.name)));
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need a second *some* iteration:

```
johnRemoved = someArray.filter( obj => !removeArray.some( obj2 => obj.name === obj2.name ));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `filter` with the `this` object equal to the set of names that need removal (a `Set` for efficiency):

```js
someArray = [{name:"Kristian", lines:"2,5,10"},
             {name:"John", lines:"1,19,26,96"},
             {name:"Brian",lines:"3,9,62,36" }];

removeArray = [{name:"Kristian", lines:"2,5,10"},
             {name:"Brian",lines:"3,9,62,36" }];
             
someArray = someArray.filter(function(obj) {
    return !this.has(obj.name);
}, new Set(removeArray.map(obj => obj.name)));

console.log(someArray);
```

Comment: Why not `(set => obj => !set.has(obj))(new Set(..))` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
someArray.filter(i => !removeArray.map(j => j.name).includes(i.name));
```

or if you don't want to go beyond ES6 with `includes`:

```
someArray.filter(i => !removeArray.some(j => j.name === i.name));
```

or using `reduce`:

```
someArray.reduce((acc, i) => {
  !removeArray.some(j => j.name === i.name) && acc.push(i);
  return acc;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
someArray.filter(function(item) {
    return !removeArray.some(function(r) { return r.name == item.name && r.lines == item.lines })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That should do the trick.

```
const removed = someArray.filter((e) => {
    return removeArray.find(r => r.name === e.name) !== undefined;
});
```

Comment: why `const`?, and not `var` or `let`

Comment: You can use whatever you want. I am primarily using `const` because it prevents you from re-assigning new value to variable.  [Here](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-es6-var-let-or-const-ba58b8dcde75) you've got pretty nice article explaining the difference between those keywords.

Comment: In this case to work with variables of our application we change them frequently, it is better to use `var` or` let. `const` more I would use it for configuration variables for example ...